# Why am I getting "unexpected keyword_end error" with this block?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, block

I seem to be getting an error for this block, and I'm not quite sure why. If I remove the `break` and the counter it works, but if I add them I get this error:

Error:

```
/home/rails_apps/Twitter_App/app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:133: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
/home/rails_apps/Twitter_App/app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:145: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Code:

```
@followers2.each do |follow| 
  @followers3 << Twitter.user(follow)
  break if i >10
  i++
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was an idiot, I totally forgot that Ruby doesn't make use of the increment operator....doh!

Changed from:

```
@followers2.each do |follow| 
  @followers3 << Twitter.user(follow)
  break if i >10
  i++
end
```

To this:

```
@followers2.each do |follow| 
  @followers3 << Twitter.user(follow)
  break if i >10
  i+=1
end
```

Answer (score -1):

On the last line you are using the binary infix `+` operator but you never provide the second operand. Ruby is expecting the operand on the next line (whitespace is allowed between an operator and its operands) but instead it hits the `end` keyword. You need to provide the second operand.